# want to overwrite created angularJS object in another services but it gets reinitialize after ctrl +f5 in application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 services in angular js, one is to declare objects with its default values and other one to assign new value to those objects. I am able to use this object after rewrite in controllers but when i refresh browser (Ctrl+F5), it gets reinitialized to its default value.

Please help.

This works good, but after ctrl+F5, it again set to false.

```
    var appl = angular.module('app');
appl.service('service1', ['$rootScope', '$modal', function($rootScope, $modal) {
    this.prefs = {
        rememberMe: false,
        popIt: function() {
            $modal.open({       
                templateUrl: "views/flag-message.html",
                controller: "flagMessageCtrl",
        });
        }
    };
}]);


var appl = angular.module('app');
appl.service('service2', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'service1', function($rootScope, $scope, service1) {  

        service1.prefs.rememberMe = true;

}]);

var appl = angular.module('app');

appl.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'service1', function ($scope, Restangular, service1) {

alert(service1.prefs.rememberMe);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in browser without setting cookies and avoiding writing long code in angular js by storing value in `window.name`.

The value stored in `window.name` persists in same browser tab even after you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will get reset once you refresh the page, When you refresh a page all your JavaScript context is lost

You can use localStorage, it will remain until you close the browser.

```
$localStorage.item = []
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LPIsG61pZrVOS7GKAmu1)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior. When you hit ctrl+f5, your whole angular app will be reloaded. If you wish certain settings to be persisted, you should use some kind of library that allows you to do that.

A great alternative is [angular-storage from Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) which will allow you to use different browser stores (local, session and cookies) to persist values/settings between session.